# Override GWT theme body margin css attribute?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT. I see that the gwt "clean" theme (the default one?) makes our body element have a 10px margin:

```
body {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;  <------
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

In my own css file, I set the margin to 0px, but it seems that GWT's keeps winning (maybe because it gets loaded last?).

What's the right way to override their setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities:

- You can use `margin: 0px !important` (this is the "brute-force" approach).
- Or you can give your body a class like `<body class="myApp">...</body>`, and then in your CSS, use `body.myApp { ... }`. This will take precedence, because `body.myApp` is a more specific selector than `body`.
- Or you can simply not use any theme at all (which is often a good idea if you want to create a fresh layout without worrying which attributes you'll have to override)

Comment: all option tested on gwt 2.9.0 , NOT WORKING

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to load your css file by using clientbundle. (assume that playground.css is your css file)

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    public static Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Source("playground.css")
    CssResource getPlaygroundCSS();
}
```

***Note: playground.css is located in the same package as the Resources interface.***

---

in the onmoduleload:

```
public class Playground implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Resources.INSTANCE.getPlaygroundCSS().ensureInjected();

        Label lblHelloWorld = new Label("Hello World");
        RootPanel.get().add(lblHelloWorld);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This solution work on gwt 2.9.0 , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS:

> body { 
>       background-color: #FFFFD2 !important;  }

works fine to change the background color.